# how to send variable from function to another function in a same controller with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with send variable data from function to another function in a same controller orderProcess :

this my controller orderProcess :

```
function endOrder(){
    $datap['invoice_pad'] = $invoice;
    $datap['date_end'] = date('d-m-Y');
    $datap['total_order'] = $grt;
    //$datap i want send to the function controller order()
}

function order(){
    //here should be $datap accepted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

function endOrder()
{

```
$datap['invoice_pad'] = $invoice;

$datap['date_end'] = date('d-m-Y');

$datap['total_order'] = $grt;

$this->order($datap);
```

}

function order($data){

```
echo $data['invoice_pad'];

echo $data['date_end'];

echo $data['total_order'];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function endOrder(){
    $datap['invoice_pad'] = $invoice;
    $datap['date_end'] = date('d-m-Y');
    $datap['total_order'] = $grt;
    return $datap;
}

function order(){
    $datap = $this->endOrder();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I will declare a variable and use it to pass around any data that is needed. But above answer also able to achieve what you wanted.

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->_datap = [];
}

function endOrder()
{
    $this->_datap['invoice_pad'] = $invoice;
    $this->_datap['date_end']    = date('d-m-Y');
    $this->_datap['total_order'] = $grt;
}

function order(){
    print_r(this->_datap);
}
```